# left menu on flexbox model doesn't expand it's height dynamically

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a static left column with a right side body.  On page load the left menu fits the browser correctly.  If i resize the browser it continues to fit nicely.  However when the body of the right column expands past the left column the left menu doesn't expand with it (with dynamic content).

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/037exh8n/

HTML

```
<body>
<div class="sidebar">
  <ul>
    <li>Menu Item</li>
    <li>Menu Item</li>
    <li>Menu Item</li>
    <li>Menu Item</li>
    <li>Menu Item</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="main">
   <div class="content"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
html,body {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #7F7E7E;
  color: #000000;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  padding: 0;
  margin : 0;
}

.sidebar {
  height: 100%;
  flex: 0 0 250px;
  background-color: #000;
  padding-left: 20px;
  color:white;
}
.main {
  flex: 1;
}
```

If you click on the button you can see that the left menu doesn't expand with the content.

What am I missing?   I notice if I got into the debugger in chrome that the html body height never updates.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not working as expected because you're explicitly setting the `html`/`body` element's height to `100%`, and then you're setting the left menu `.sidebar` element's height to `100%` as well.

In doing so, the left menu's height will not expand beyond `100%` (even if you add more content, like in your case). It seems like you want to give those elements a `min-height` of `100%` instead. In doing so, the height will be at least `100%`, and then expand based on the content.

[**Updated Example**](https://jsfiddle.net/s5owtz16/)

```
html, body {
  min-height: 100%;
  background-color: #7F7E7E;
  color: #000;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  margin: 0;
}
```

Side note: You only have to set `min-height` on the `html`/`body` elements since the `.sidebar` element is a flexbox child and it will expand to match the parent element's height, in this case the `body` element's minimum height of `100%`. Just omit the height on the `.sidebar` element completely like in the linked example above.

---

Alternatively, you could also just use viewport-percentage units and set a `min-height` of `100vh` directly on the `.sidebar` element:

[**Updated Example**](https://jsfiddle.net/9atqw6m3/)

```
.sidebar {
  min-height: 100vh;
  flex: 0 0 250px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you!  That totally makes sense.